# Org mode: How to schedule repeating tasks for the first Saturday of every month?

Tags: org-mode

I'm using org-mode to schedule tasks.

Is there a straightforward way to schedule a task that occurs on the first Saturday of every month?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Org Mode has a great documentation, use it.
`(info "(org) Deadlines and scheduling")`

> You may use timestamps with repeaters in scheduling and deadline
>   entries.  Org mode will issue early and late warnings based on the
>   assumption that the timestamp represents the nearest instance of the
>   repeater.  However, the use of diary sexp entries like `<%%(diary-float t
>   42)>' in scheduling and deadline timestamps is limited.  Org mode does
>   not know enough about the internals of each sexp function to issue
>   early and late warnings.  However, it will show the item on each day
>   where the sexp entry matches.

```
* My Task
  <%%(diary-float t 6 1)>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did look at the documentation, but until a google search I did a few moments ago, I didn't know what a Diary-style sexp entry was -- so I glanced over the relevant section. Thanks again!

Comment: the sexp should be (org-float t 6 1)

Comment: Be sure to note nberth's "answer" below: org-float is now obsolete and you need to use diary-float, which has a slightly different syntax.

Comment: This solution and the documentation in the "repeating tasks" section leave a lot to be desired when using this function along side agenda views. On top of a lack of early and late warnings, you lose the ability to mark a single instance of a repeated task done. Instead, it will mark the entire task done and no longer repeat. The answer by cfy resolves these issues, albeit with a fair amount of custom code.

Comment: This information is in the section "Deadlines and scheduling", not in "Repeated tasks", where you (I) would look for it - I couldn't find it either...

Answer (score 18):

`org-float` is now obsolete (see [this commit](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=commitdiff;h=b27a020a835f67c1c61bd2bb1a03accc4ad4b453)). From now on, you'll have to use `diary-float` in place of `org-float`.

(Sorry for the noise: this does not deserve a full answer, but for now I don't have enough "reputation" to comment.)

Answer (score 12):

Using sexp in scheduling and deadline timestamp is limited,like info says

> Org mode does not know enough about the internals of each sexp function to issue 
>   early and late warnings.

I write a elisp code to change the timestamp automatically,with it,all you need to do is setting a property.

the elisp code is [here](https://github.com/chenfengyuan/elisp/blob/master/next-spec-day.el)

1. add `(load "/path/to/next-spec-day")` to your dot emacs file.
2. set `NEXT-SPEC-DEADLINE` and/or `NEXT-SPEC-SCHEDULED` property of a TODO task,like this:

   ```
   * test
     :PROPERTIES:
     :NEXT-SPEC-SCHEDULED: (org-float t 6 1)
     :END:
   ```

   The value of NEXT-SPEC-SCHEDULED is a sexp will return `non-nil` if `date` is the first Saturday of the month
3. Then,when you change the TODO state of that tasks,the timestamp will be changed automatically(include lead time of warnings settings).It becomes:

   ```
   * TODO test
     SCHEDULED: <2013-01-05 Sat>
     :PROPERTIES:
     :NEXT-SPEC-SCHEDULED: (org-float t 6 1)
     :END:
   ```